# Libraries to image zoom in another place

Tags: javascript, css

What I need to do is introduce libraries to zoom in on a specific location from one image to another place when hovering over a image.

> See an example for my explanation in this link:
> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_zoom.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [magnifier.js](https://mark-rolich.github.io/Magnifier.js)
or [EasyZoom](https://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/).
they have decent documention as well.